# Creating a Jquery function to work with multiple buttons that work with multiple boxes

Tags: jquery, css, html, function, button

Ok, so I've been having fun coding for awhile now. I'm still pretty new but am working on what I know. I have come across this road block where I am trying to figure out how to get jquery to allow me to the same function for multiple buttons and each button reacts with a different box. Basically one button will make sure all boxes are closed ".hide()" and then open the specific one. as of right now I cannot get the specific button when clicked to react with the specific box.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hide1").click(function(){
if ($("#box1").css('display') == "none"){
    $(".box").hide();
    $(".bttn").css("opacity", ".5");
    $("#box1").fadeToggle();
    $("#hide1").css("opacity", "1");}
else
{
$("#box1").fadeToggle();
$("#hide1").css("opacity", ".5");
}   
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hide2").click(function(){
if ($("#box2").css('display') == "none"){
    $(".box").hide();
    $(".bttn").css("opacity", ".5");
    $("#box2").fadeToggle();
    $("#hide2").css("opacity", "1");}
        else
{
$("#box2").fadeToggle();
$("#hide2").css("opacity", ".5");
}
});
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li style="opacity:.5;" id="hide1" class="bttn"></li>
<li style="opacity:.5;" id="hide2" class="bttn"></li>
</ul>
<div style="display:none;" id="box1" class="box">
<div style="display:none;" id="box2" class="box">
```

as of right now this set up works. But I was wondering if there was a way to condense the jquery into one function so that clicking on either button (li) would allow it to work with it's respective division.

https://jsfiddle.net/nathanahartmann/5h3r1671/

Comment: If you're going to keep the same order you can check the index of the button clicked in the UL and then use that number on the box class.

Comment: I have never had to do this before. Would you be able to show a quick way to be able to set this up?

Comment: I'm working on one right now, I'll post it when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the data attribute. And then, make a function with jQuery for all buttons.

This will link the li to the #box1

```
<li style="opacity:.5;" id="hide1" class="bttn" data-target="#box1"></li>
```

And in your jQuery, retrieve the button.

```
$('.bttn').on('click', function(){
    var target = $($(this).data('target'));
    $('.bttn').css('opacity', '.5');
    if(target.css('display') == "none"){    
        $('.box').hide();
        target.fadeToggle();
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
    }

    target.fadeToggle();
});
```

It's good if you have a lot of box.

Here's an example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o03zqr79/1/)

Comment: you're amazing KayVan! This is the code I ended up using to get this to work! you're a life saver! much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's just targeting using the indexes.

https://jsfiddle.net/u1cksgyh/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bttn').click(function() {
    var btn = $(this).index();
    box = $('.box');

    $(".bttn").css("opacity", ".5");
    $(".box").hide();

    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
    $(box[btn]).fadeToggle();

  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it! this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can make use of the *this* keyword in combination with a naming convention used on your id attributes. I would recommend adding dashes between the names and numbers like so:

```
<ul>
    <li style="opacity:.5;" id="hide-1" class="bttn"></li>
    <li style="opacity:.5;" id="hide-2" class="bttn"></li>
</ul>
<div style="display:none;" id="box-1" class="box">
<div style="display:none;" id="box-2" class="box">
```

Then, you can attach a single click event to your 'bttn' class and use a function that grabs the currently clicked element using *this* and look at it's id. Store the number in a variable and you can use it to manipulate your other elements that have matching numbers. It could look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bttn").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.attr('id').split('-')[0];

        if ($this.css('display') == "none") {
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".bttn").css("opacity", ".5");
            $("#box-" + id).fadeToggle();
            $("#hide-" + id).css("opacity", "1");
        } else {
            $("#box-" + id).fadeToggle();
            $("#hide-" + id).css("opacity", ".5");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks SM! I appreciate the time taken to answer my question! this helped me figure out a solution!